# Catch a specific value in a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

How to catch a particular value in a dataset and assign it to a label in gridview??

```
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        Label lblName = e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
        ds = Common.RunByDate(lblName.Text);
        DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;

        ddl.DataTextField = "RunDate";
        ddl.DataValueField = "RunDate";
        ddl.DataSource = ds;
        ddl.DataBind();
        var items = ddl.Items;
```

in the DS i am getting three values i have to catch a specific value

```
TempName    Rundate   RunBy  

test    2012-10-11  chandu
```

as i am getting three values from a dataset how can i catch the RunBy name?? how can i filter for it

Answer (score 0):

Use [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) class and it's [RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) prperty where you push valid `SQL` query to filter the records according to some logic you define.  Assign like a binding the `DataView`

Comment: Can you show me some code for this?I am getting three values in the dataset and based on the dropdown latest value i have to bind the label in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few options

```
var items = ddl.Items;
```

[FindByText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbytext.aspx)

```
var result = items.FindByText(text);
```

[FindByValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue.aspx)

```
var result = items.FindByValue(value);
```

Comment: I am getting the values dynamically.

Comment: Updated the question can you check once?

Comment: do you just want the values back from dataset?

Comment: Get the specific value from dataset and bind it to the label inside a gridview

Comment: string title = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RunBy"].ToString() this worked for me